# c# unit conversion library for food amounts

Tags: c#, implementation, units-of-measurement

I want to implement a simple unit conversion library for food measurements, ie cups teaspoons. pinch, milliliters, ounces, liters, grams, pounds etc etc etc.
Are there any libraries out there that I can use allready, if not I want to roll my own in the pseudo manner below:

```
enum Unit
{
    Centimeters = 0,
    Meter = 1,
    Kilometer = 2           
}


//| |           |   0       |  1    |   2       |
//----------------------------------------------
//| |           |Centimeters| Meters| Kilometers|
//----------------------------------------------
//|0|Centimeters|1        | 0.01  | 0.000001  |
//----------------------------------------------
//|1|Meters  |100        | 1      | 1000     |
//----------------------------------------------
//|2|Kilometers |100000     | 1000  | 1         |
//----------------------------------------------


public float Convert(Unit UnitFrom, Unit UnitTo, UnitValue)
{
   float factor = UnitMatrix[UnitFrom][Unit UnitTo];
   return UnitValue * factor;
}

//Usage
Convert(Unit.Kilometers, Unit.Meters, 5)
// Lookup factor in this case would be the one at [2, 1] i.e. 1000 so output is 5000
```

Pointers, pitfalls, too naive? Any help would be useful.
A current opensource implementation that I can study would be great too.
TIA

Comment: This open source app does much of what you want so I'd crack it open to see how. http://www.gnu.org/software/units/

Comment: You need to know at least the density of your material. Since some of your units are masses, others volumes.

Comment: Actually, I think the solution you propose in the question looks best.  Especially for recipes, where there are relatively few different units and no dimensional analysis.

Comment: Sweet, let me dig a little in some of the projects proposed in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@n4rzul, I have started developing an open-source units-of-measurement library in C#, that could easily be extended with any unit of your request. Please have a look at the project website at Github, https://github.com/cureos/csunits, and see if this library meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks Anders. I will have a look see this afternoon. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

I recently released Units.NET on [GitHub](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) and on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet/).

It gives you all the common units and conversions. It is light-weight, unit tested and supports PCL.

Although I haven't incorporated all the food units yet, it is on the list of things to add.

Example conversions:

```
Length meter = Length.FromMeters(1);
double cm = meter.Centimeters; // 100
double yards = meter.Yards; // 1.09361
double feet = meter.Feet; // 3.28084
double inches = meter.Inches; // 39.3701
```

Parse and Get Culture-Specific Abbreviations:

```
var us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var norwegian = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");

Unit.Tablespoon == UnitSystem.Create(us).Parse("tbsp")
Unit.Tablespoon == UnitSystem.Create(norwegian).Parse("ss")  

"T" == UnitSystem.GetDefaultAbbreviation(Unit.Tablespoon, us)
"ss" == UnitSystem.GetDefaultAbbreviation(Unit.Tablespoon, norwegian)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while ago
http://www.carbonatethis.com/archives/38

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will meet all your needs but this looks to cover a good range of measurements:

http://unitconvertlibrary.codeplex.com/

Though it looks to be in development, and there is only one class available in the source repository

Answer (score 0):

I have also developed a units library.  It is available on NuGet [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/JKor.Units/). The repository is on my bitbucket account linked from my profile here on SO.